# what is the maximum number of achievements a player can have in an 2-player innovation game?

Tags: puzzles, innovation

Considering the game of innovation  (see, eg, https://boardgamearena.com/gamepanel?game=innovation) a 2-player game ends on 6 achievements.

Usually an achievement takes an action to complete, but special achievements occur when a condition is met.

Therefore, it is possible to end the game with more then 6 achievements, if the last 2 (or more) where special achievements. For example, you can have the empire achievement and the universe achievement met with a single meld.

I am trying to come up with a way to do the 5 achievements at once.

For 4 achievements, we can have empiricism causing a splay (if the last unsplayed color, wonder achievement) with the melding of an ten (if the last color with card < 8, universe) that might reveal clocks (world achievement) and other symbols (that might be sufficient for the empire achievement).

(for the purposes of this question, let's exclude expansions. I will ask another question for expansions if no solution can be found)

Comment: Are you including expansions?

Comment: lets start excluding expansions. If that is not enough, I will ask another question including them.

Comment: The rulebook doesn't seem completely clear on this point, but I believe the game ends immediately when someone achieves the 6th achievement? So to get multiple they would need to be claimed completely simultaneously, not just caused by the same action/dogma, right?

Comment: idk. We can try to answer the two questions... But I fear that immediately (rather than finish your action) will lead to a boring answer (perhaps 2)

Comment: You can do at least 3 exactly simultaneously, but I agree that if you don't get to finish your action, then it's clearly impossible to do all 5, because you could never simultaneously cause a splay and change the value of your top cards.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a way (assuming that you get to finish your action).

Dogma on computers, melds self-service. (universe achievement) and splays a color up (wonder). self services is used to dogma socialism (monument, empire and world follow from tucking many cards)